# How do get the GTK mime-type/content-type information from the file extension

Tags: gtk, gnome

I'm not allowed to access the file content (for performance reasons), so using GFile is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need g_content_type_guess.

In Python (GTK2):

```
import gio
gio.content_type_guess('foo.pdf')
```

This will return `application/pdf`

In Python (GTK3):

```
from gi.repository import Gio
content_type, val = Gio.content_type_guess('filename=foo.pdf', data=None)
```

content_type will contain `application/pdf`

More details in the documentation: http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GContentType.html#g-content-type-guess

Answer (score 2):

Looks like GIO's content type detection is based on the file extension (when there is an extension).

```
$ ./file /bin/sh
application/x-executable
$ cp /bin/sh a.wav
$ ./file a.wav
audio/x-wav
```

where ./file is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys, gio
f = gio.File(sys.argv[1])
info = f.query_info('standard::content-type')
print info.get_content_type()
```

Comment: I really doubt that GIO is using the file tool.

Comment: It's not entirely based on extension: for files with unknown (or missing) extension it will "sniff" the content for magic numbers